# C++ Making abstract class which uses structs

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, struct, abstract

So I was working on modifying a big class in C++, and now I got a task to make it abstract, so one could easily switch between the old version and my modified class. Both versions should remain, but now as something like `class c1 : public c` & `class c2 : public c`.
The problem is that it is a really big class with a lot of functions which use few structs. It looks something like this.

```
struct1{
    int i1, i2;
}
struct2{
    string s;
    float f;
}
class c{
    void f1(struct1 s, float d);
    void f2(std::vector<int> &v1);
}
```

And modified one:

```
struct1{
    float i1, i2;
};
struct2{
    string s;
    double f;
    string s2;
};
class c{
    void f1(struct1 s, float d);
    void f2(std::vector<float> &v1);

}
```

So not only do function implementation change, but also structure of this structs and parameters type in some containers. My question is what (from a point of view of clean & well-written code) could I do to make `class c` abstract? How can I override those structures to be different? Hide variables from base structures by variables of different types? Inside f1 & f2 are direct operations on members of struct1 & struct2, like
`if(struct1.i1 < someInt) doSomething();` and in the modified class 
`if(struct1.i1 <someFloat) doSomethingElse();`. 
Another problem are those containers of different parameter as arguments of functions. My idea is to make those containers into structures/classes  which then can be implemented differently, or to make those parameters into structs, like `std::vector<struct3> &v` and then struct3 could also be implemented in different ways depending on what is needed.
Thanks for all answers!

Comment: I think you're reading too much into this - if you need to make the class abstract (and the spec didn't specify anything about the parameter types), the parameters can remain the same. If you wanted to have the parameters change to support multiple types, you're probably wanting templates instead.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Those two are different implementations of the same class, and both should remain, but now as
`class c1 : public c` & `class c2: public c`. So I have to do something with those parameters, because c1 and c2 have different structs and function parameters.

Comment: Sounds like you are violating the _one definition rule_. I have a feeling this could be the XY problem.

Comment: If `c1` and `c2` will be just different implementation of the same base abstract class then they will have same structs and function parameters.

Comment: Once you changed the public interface it isnt possible to "easily switch between the old version and my modified class" without modifiying calling code. Adding an abstract class doesnt make it much better

Comment: Thanks for comments. I know that interface should stay the same, so I'm wondering what could I do to make them identical.

Comment: From your code I don't see how `struct2` is used by old or new `c`.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, I tried to keep it simple. I wrote it to show that there are multiple structs with different fields.

Comment: fyi C++ doesn't have structs. It has classes. In C++ the `struct` keyword declares a class. E.g. `struct X{};` defines a class named `X`. It is a bit confusing, agreed, but it was done for compatibility with C